# Did Sybok have any means of preventing a ship from beaming out the hostages on Nimbus III?

Tags: star-trek, the-final-frontier

In *Star Trek V: The Final Frontier*, the Vulcan Sybok creates a hostage situation on Nimbus III as part of a plan to capture a ship. It is successful, partly because the *Enterprise-A* is in disrepair and the transporter doesn't work, so they have to take a shuttle.

But what if a working ship was dispatched instead?* Did Sybok have any means of preventing them from beaming out the hostages? That seems like a way that would have ended the conflict pretty quickly.

<sup>* Or to address a plot hole: what Starfleet just put Kirk on another ship around Earth. You know, the headquarters of the Federation! Or is the *Excelsior*, sabotaged in *Star Trek III* the only other ship they have?</sup>

Comment: I would normally come up with some elaborate rationalization to answer you; however, this question relates almost entirely to Star Trek V. That way lies madness.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aside from the planet's sand-filled atmosphere (which apparently makes it somewhat problematic to get a solid lock) Sybok had no way of preventing the hostages from being beamed up, however the whole

> "I've taken hostages"

plot was **simply a ruse for him to gain access to a high quality starship**.

Assuming the Enterprise (or a Klingon ship or a Romulan ship) had arrived in orbit with a functional transporter, they would have immediately beamed up the ambassadors, **all of whom were under Sybok's mind control** and they would have then helped him to take control of the ship, presumably by ordering the Captain of the vessel to beam Sybok up to the ship for interrogation.